# How to check whether the entered Date in Textfield is valid or not in Dart/Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Im taking day month and year in 3 Textfields but none of the DateTime property or function is providing the validation.

I have used DateTime.parse(str) to get the date but it adds the remaining months to the year if month field is entered with more then 12 same for days too.

```
bool isDate(String str) {
  try {
    DateTime.parse(str);
    return true;
  } catch (e) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

*I want if some one enters '20053050' to the string to be false not true.
But this functions always return true !!!*

[image]

Comment: If you are just looking for a convenient way to get a certain date from a user, there are a couple good packages that can make that easier - maybe check out https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_datetime_picker or https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_date_picker

Comment: Use `DateTime.tryParse(str)`

Answer (score 5):

There's simple method you can try now. Which is [tryParse](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.5/dart-core/DateTime/tryParse.html) method.
It simply returns null for invalid date format.

```
if(DateTime.tryParse(timeString) != null){
  DateTime date = DateTime.parse(timeString);
}
```

Comment: `print(DateTime.tryParse('9999-99-99'));` outputs `// 10007-06-07 00:00:00.000`. Same with `DateTime.tryParse('99999999')`.

Answer (score 5):

Use `parseStrict` instead of just `parse`:

```
 DateFormat format = DateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
 DateTime dayOfBirthDate = format.parseStrict(value); //33.08.2001 - is invalid, 31.13.2001 - is invalid too

 DateFormat format = DateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
 DateTime dayOfBirthDate = format.parse(value); //33.08.2001 - will change to 2.09.2001 (same with months)
```

Answer (score 4):

It seems to be an issue that the DateTime constructor allows invalid ranges: [DateTime.parse should throw an error on invalid date...](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/11189)

Here is a workaround: [How to check if a given Date exists in DART?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57080005/how-to-check-if-a-given-date-exists-in-dart)

You could use it like this:

```
bool isValidDate(String input) {
  try {
    final date = DateTime.parse(input);
    final originalFormatString = toOriginalFormatString(date);
    return input == originalFormatString;
  } catch(e) {
    return false;
  }
}

String toOriginalFormatString(DateTime dateTime) {
  final y = dateTime.year.toString().padLeft(4, '0');
  final m = dateTime.month.toString().padLeft(2, '0');
  final d = dateTime.day.toString().padLeft(2, '0');
  return "$y$m$d";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try to collect the date as a string (e.g. `String _enteredDate`) and have it converted to the date format you want using `DateFormat` with your formatting preference and parsing the string using `DateTime.parse`. E.g.:

```
_formattedDate = DateFormat('MM-dd-yyyy').format(DateTime.parse(_enteredDate))
```

If the user inputs and invalid date format, there should be an error which you can catch and alert.

Answer (score 2):

```
bool isDate(String input, String format) {
  try {
    final DateTime d = DateFormat(format).parseStrict(input);
    //print(d);
    return true;
  } catch (e) {
    //print(e);
    return false;
  }
}
```

Check Date.

```
String inputDate = "2022-02-20"; 
if (isDate(inputDate, "yyyy-MM-dd")) {
    print("$inputDate Date Valid");
} else {
    print("$inputDate Date notValid");
}
```

> **"2022-02-20" Date Valid**

> **"2022-02-30" Date notValid**

[Yann39 Answered from.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61887488/flutter-converting-string-to-date-and-date-to-integer)