# Flutter: Converting string to date and date to integer

Tags: flutter

I have a date coming from some JSON in the format "2020-05-19". I need to convert this to a DateTime variable so I can format it back to a string for displaying, but i also need to use the DateTime value and add x number of days to it. So I also need to be able to convert it to an integer so I can add on (x_days * 86400000).

Can anyone tell me how to do this, or is there a better way to do what I'm trying to do?

Cheers,

Paul

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To convert a String to date you can use DateTime's [`parseStrict`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/intl/DateFormat/parseStrict.html) method :

```dart
String dateStr = "2020-05-19";
DateTime date = DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", 'en').parseStrict(dateStr);
```

You could also create a helper method :

```dart
static DateTime convertToDate(String input, String format) {
  try {
    final DateTime d = DateFormat(format, 'en').parseStrict(input);
    return d;
  } catch (e) {
    return null;
  }
}
```

Then use it like this :

```dart
DateTime date = convertToDate("2020-05-19", "yyyy-MM-dd");
```

I used "en" locale but you can change it as needed or pass it as parameter.

For looser parsing, use [parse](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/intl/DateFormat/parse.html).

---

Then to add days use the DateTime's [`add`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.2/dart-core/DateTime/add.html) method, for example to add 2 days :

```dart
date.add(Duration(days: 2));
```

Comment: Excellent. Thanks so much. Have a great day.